# SSRS Conditional default StartDate

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am attempting to set the default start date of a report to the previous business day, which is

```
dateadd(dd,-1,getdate())
```

on all days except Monday when it is

```
dateadd(dd,-3,getdate())
```

Prior to this report being converted to an SSRS report this was handled in the proc with the query

```
declare @startDate datetime = 
    (
        select
            case
                when DATENAME(dw, CONVERT(date, getdate())) = 'Monday' then cast(Convert(date, dateadd(DD,-3,CONVERT(date, getdate()))) as nvarchar(100))
                else cast(Convert(date, dateadd(DD,-1,@today)) as nvarchar(100))
            end
    )
```

How would I implement this conditional start date using an SSRS =IIF statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Upon more research I've discovered the method to do this is:

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day
    , Switch(DatePart(DateInterval.WeekDay, Today()) = 2, -3
        ,DatePart(DateInterval.WeekDay, Today()) = 1, -2
        ,True, -1)
    , Today())
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use switch personally:

```
=Switch(
WeekdayName(Weekday(today))="Monday",dateadd(DateInterval.Day,-3,today),
True,dateadd(DateInterval.Day,-1,today) 
)
```